# SDL + OpenGL, irregular frame times with periodic spikes

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I was developing an application with SDL and glad. I noticed that there were some small freezes in the animations. I have written a separate project with the minimal functionality and I found the issue appears even with a very basic setup.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>

using namespace std;

// the application will close after this amount of time
const float MILISECONDS_TO_CLOSE = 10 * 1000;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    SDL_Window* window =
        SDL_CreateWindow(
            "tracer",
            100, 100,
            800, 600,
            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
        );

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    // SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);   // this line mitigates the problem but just slightly

    if (!gladLoadGL())
    {
        cout << "gladLoadGL failed" << endl;
    }

    const GLubyte *oglVersion = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    std::cout << "This system supports OpenGL Version: " << oglVersion << std::endl;
    const GLubyte *gpuVendor = glGetString(GL_VENDOR);
    std::cout << "Graphics card: " << gpuVendor << std::endl;

    glClearColor(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f, 1.0f);

    vector<unsigned> deltas;
    deltas.reserve(10 * MILISECONDS_TO_CLOSE);

    static unsigned firstTime, prevTime, curTime;
    firstTime = prevTime = curTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    while (true)
    {
        // compute delta time
        curTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        unsigned dt = curTime - prevTime;
        prevTime = curTime;
        deltas.push_back(dt);

        // close the application after some time
        if (curTime - firstTime > MILISECONDS_TO_CLOSE) break;

        // handle closing events
        SDL_Event event;
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE || event.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    // save recorded deltas to a file
    fstream f("out.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    for (unsigned dt : deltas) f << dt << endl;
    f << flush;
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The program records the time between frames during 10 seconds and saves the result in a text file.

I plotted the data using python I got this:

[image]

The horizontal axis tells the frame time in milliseconds. The vertical axis tells the time passed since the last frame. Also in milliseconds.

As you can see the time between frames is very irregular and there are periodic spikes (about 1 seconds between spikes).

I have uploaded the CMake project to a [github repository](https://github.com/tuket/test_frames), so you can test it if you wish.

I have tested with both my integrated and dedicated GPUs (Intel 530HD and NVIDIA GTX 960M).

The SDL version is 2.0.5.

I tested it on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**EDIT:**
I have ported the application to GLFW and the same happens. So, it is very unlikelly that there is a bug in SDL. I have updated the git repo accordingly, now there are two CMake projects.

**EDIT2:**
I have tested it in another computer and works fine.
[image]
I have no clue what's happening. Could it be a hardware problem? Then why it doesn't happen when I run other applications?

Driver problem? Very unlikelly because it happens both using the Intel and NVIDIA GPUs. Also, it happens on both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Seems that the spikes are every second. Maybe you got another process running on your computer that wakes up every second and eats all the CPU time. Did you try your program on another computer ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention OS and version. I will update the question

Comment: @BrunoLevy I haven't tried in other computers but I tried two different OSs installed on the same machine. I will try to find another computer to test it.

Comment: Is this on a laptop?

Comment: Does switching to `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))` help?  Right now you're dequeuing a single event per frame.

Comment: @Stefan Monov Yes: Asus GL552VW

Comment: @genpfault Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work though

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar behavior (though with longer&lower plateaus, not spikes) caused by the CPU overheating and hence deciding to lower clock rate temporarily. If that happens with your PC, you can try to upgrade your internal coolers or add external ones. Or just lower the temperature setting on the air conditioner in your room.

Naturally, it was always more an issue during summer.

[Here's where I've posted about it](https://superuser.com/q/397491).

Comment: That's interesting. In the code I provided the loop is completelly unlimeted, so it's true that it clould cause overheating. I tried to add `SDL_Delay(10)' (100 fps at most) so overheating should not be an issue. The spikes are still there ([img](http://i.imgur.com/PzTMGCs.png)). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user1754322: When I was overheating, I had vsync on, so 60fps at most.

Comment: I tried enabling vsync too and the same happens. I believe it's not overheating, after all, I have used other interactive applications without problems. It wouldn't make sense that a loop that doesn't do any work at all (99% of the time is iddle) overheats and other applications don't. Besides this is a gaming laptop. Thank you